# JavaFX - How to sync up TextArea scroll bar and ScrollPane scroll bar

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TextArea` element which itself has a scroll bar and a separate `ScrollPane` which has a scroll bar. How can i make one of the scroll bars match their position with the other one?

I have been looking up methods for acquiring the position of a scroll bar.

For `ScrollPane` there is `.getVvalue()` which returns a double from 0 to 1. Basically like a percentage value of sort.

For `TextArea` there's `.getScrollTop()` which also returns a double but it's maximum value is unknown pretty much unless you manually scroll the bar down to find out the position at the very bottom.

Since they both return different values I would have to know the maximum position for both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TextArea` has one child, which is its `ScrollPane`. The percentage scroll can therefore be found as

```
((ScrollPane) textArea.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0)).getVvalue()
```

Hope this helps!