# Make all elements (including 2 list views) scroll together in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a VBox, and within the VBox are some elements including 3 headers (3 stack panes) and 2 list views, is it possible to make everything in the VBox scroll together?

Here is an image of my application

[image]

This is the FXML code for this view

```java
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <StackPane prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="stack-welcome" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <children>

         <!-- WELCOME MESSAGE -->
         <Label styleClass="label-welcome" text="Hi! I'm Volant :)" />
      </children>
   </StackPane>
   <StackPane prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="stack-header" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <children>
        <Label styleClass="label-header" text="TRIP LIST" />
      </children>
   </StackPane>

   <StackPane prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="trip-list-header" style="-fx-border-width: 0px 0px 2px 0px" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <children>
         <Label styleClass="label-header" text="UPCOMING TRIPS" />
      </children>
   </StackPane>
   <ListView fx:id="tripListViewUpcoming" prefWidth="247.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />

   <StackPane prefHeight="15.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="trip-list-header" style="-fx-border-width: 2px 0px 2px 0px" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
      <children>
         <Label styleClass="label-header" text="PAST TRIPS" />
      </children>
   </StackPane>
   <ListView fx:id="tripListViewPast" prefWidth="247.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" />

</VBox>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scroll together"? Does wrapping the `VBox` in a `ScrollPane` meet your requirements?

Comment: See: [How can I make two ListViews scroll together in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372341/how-can-i-make-two-listviews-scroll-together-in-javafx). To make the content of a `StackPane` scroll add `TextArea` to it and use its [ScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526585/javafx-how-to-sync-up-textarea-scroll-bar-and-scrollpane-scroll-bar).

Comment: @c0der Hello! I have seen that post, however, I would also like to make the stack panes scroll together with the list views

Comment: _ I have seen that post_ did you implement it ? Please post [mre]. BTW  I linked two posts.

Comment: @c0der Ok I have implemented the second post and it works now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to make the whole VBox scroll together by wrapping the VBox with a scrollPane and setting `scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);`